# Resize JTable in JScrollPane by dragging

Tags: java, jtable

How can I implement the functionality of being able to resize a JTable by dragging a corner by mouse (to see more rows during a single view) which is embedded in a JScrollPane? Is their any other easy alternative way? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Add the JScrollPane to the [ComponentResizer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/resizing-components/) class.